# Store string variable in text file

Tags: powershell

I want to create a (blank) file, and optionally store a text message in it. This is my code for doing so:

```
$null = new-item "$filename" -type file
write-output ("Message: <<$message>>")
if ( -not ($message= "")) {
    Add-Content "$filename" "Message: <$message>"
}
```

The 1st line creates the file. This works.
The 2nd line visually verifies that I do in fact supply a string (say, the proverbial "hello world").
The 3rd line evaluates to `$true` and does execute its nested block.
But the 4th line stores a message saying: `Message: <>`.

I can't figure out the proper syntax for passing the *actual value* from `$message`. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong operator for comparing the `$message` value. See `Get-Help about_comparison_operators`.

By saying `if ( -not ($message= ""))`, you actually *set* the value of `$message` to be an empty string.

Instead, use `-eq`, `-ne` or simply just test it:

```
# Option 1
if ( -not ($message -eq "")) {
    Add-Content "$filename" "Message: <$message>"
}
#Option 2
if ($message -ne "") {
    Add-Content "$filename" "Message: <$message>"
}
#Option 3
if ($message) {
    Add-Content "$filename" "Message: <$message>"
}
```

Comment: Excellent, that fixed it. You probably guessed that I'm new to PS, and the syntax sometimes still seems _quite_ round-about.

Comment: @KlaymenDK Here's some _really different_ syntax for you: `${c:\temp\afile.txt} = "content to write to file with an assignment statement"`. This unusual syntax is due to PS' support of _providers_ (`help about_providers`).